# How pass value with @Param annottaion to a method

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I decided move all my jpql queries to another class, for example

```
public class QueryUtils {

public static final String  FIND_All_CLUBS= "select c from Club c order by c.club_name";

}
```

In repository I have this:

```
@Query(value = QueryUtils.FIND_All_CLUBS)
Iterable<Club> findAllAndAndOOrderByClub_name();
```

And it works fine. But I'm stuck with that thing : what if I have params in my jpql, f.e.

```
@Query(value = "select c from Comment c where c.post.post_id = :id order by c.replyTo.comment_id nulls last")
Iterable<Comment> findAllCommentsOfPost(@Param("id") long id);
```

I'm tried to write this:

```
public static String getFIND_ALL_COMMENTS_OF_POST(String id){
    return new StringBuilder("select c from Comment c where c.post.post_id = ").append(id).append(" order by c.replyTo.comment_id nulls last").toString();
}
```

But how pass param from repository to this method, this code(which I tried is not valid):

```
@Query(QueryUtils.getFIND_ALL_COMMENTS_OF_POST(id))
Iterable<Comment> findAllCommentsOfPost(@Param("id") long id);
```

Pls, help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @Param, try this one

```
@Query(value = "select c from Comment c where c.post.post_id = ?1 order by c.replyTo.comment_id nulls last")
Iterable<Comment> findAllCommentsOfPost(long id);
```